# 'git diff' between current workspace and master

Tags: git

I am a tester and have limited knowledge about Git. I have cloned a project and created a local workspace. When I want to get the latest source code, I use the `git pull` command.

Correct me if I am wrong. I think that I don't have a branch.

Now I want to know the changes between my workspace and master. In short I want to know the changes that are going to be applied on my workspace.

I have tried `git diff master`, but it returns nothing.

Comment: You always works with master. `git pull` = `git pull origin master`

Comment: I suggest you to try https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash it will help you seeing the current branch you are and gives you completion in your terminal

Comment: @MegaTron, you do not always "work with master".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the real basics of Git. I strongly recommend going through a visual Git tutorial (just google that). Also, I recommend getting the open source GUI tool **Git Extensions** so you can visually see your commits/branches and learn different commands easier.

## Some terminology and beginner's tips:

- You cloned a **remote repository** (usually called `origin` by default) into a **local repository** on your PC.
- You do have a workspace locally, but it's a combination of several things:

  - The **local Git repository** itself, where all the information about the commit history is stored, this allows you to recreate the working directory for any commit.
  - The **Working Directory** - these are ongoing changes and differences that have not yet been committed into the repository
  - The **Index** - this is where changes from the working directory have been staged and are ready to be committed.
  - The **Stash** - this is a sort of temporary commit, where you can save the current changes from your Working directory and/or index temporarily while you go off and do something else in your repository.
- Cloning actually creates a duplicate of the remote repository on your PC, that you can commit changes to your new local repository separately from the remote repository (then sync up with it using pull and push). Not only can you commit changes locally, updating the repository, but before you can commit changes locally, you must stage them into your index. Only items in the index get committed, and then only commits get pushed to the remote repository.
- When you **pull** from the remote repository, it brings down any new commits from the current branch you have checked out (with `git fetch`), and then will `git merge` your local `master` branch into the remote `master` branch that you just pulled down.
- Unless you have created a new branch and committed locally, you are likely in the `master` branch.
- Merging may cause a merge conflict that you would have to resolve before committing the merge locally, and then finally pushing your local commits to the remote.

## How to see changes ready for committing:

- If you want to see the list of changes in your working directory (unstaged) and your index (staged and ready for a commit), type `git status`.
- If you also want see the actual changes in each file that is changed, then you can type `git diff HEAD`.

Although it's really easy in Git Extensions to see the current changes - just hit the "Commit" button, and a window pops up with the working directory on top left, index on bottom left, and if you click on any file in them, you'll see all the changes for that file on the right side.

## This is Not the Diff You're Looking For

*(Sorry - couldn't resist the Star Wars quote)*

Okay, I finally understand your core question - you are not making changes to the local repository, you just want to see the changes between the repository before the pull and after the pull - to see what changed since the last time you pulled.

This can be done by getting the hash of the last commit on `master` before the pull, and then using:

```
git diff <hash of prior commit> HEAD
```

`HEAD` refers to whichever commit is currently checked out, either the current commit of the branch you checked out, or a particular commit if you checked one out directly (this is a state called a "detached HEAD"). `HEAD` will point to `master` which will should point to the latest commit in the repository after a successful pull.

Instead of using `HEAD`, you could put the actual hash of the latest commit.  Note that if you know how many commits were pulled down, you don't even need to know the commit hashes. For example, if the prior commit was two commits back, you can use:

```
git diff HEAD~2 HEAD
```

The HEAD~2 just looks two commits back in the log from HEAD, and uses that hash.

---

To do this with a GUI, in Git Extensions, you can just right-click on the prior commit and select "Compare → Compare to current branch" in order to pull up the diff window with the changes between that commit and the current location of your current branch.

The currently checked out branch/commit is shown in bold in Git Extensions, and should always be at the top of the list and have a `>master` tag next to it for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for simpler explanation.. It helped me to understand basics of git..
Also the git GUI tool helped me to visualise git.
Using `git status` we get changes in my working directory.
My question was "I want to know the changes that are going to be applied on my workspace."
Can you help me on this one?

Comment: Again, "workspace" is a fuzzy term, and I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Changes that are not yet commited, and not yet ready to commit, are in your "Working Directory".  Once you use `git add .` it will move all current changes into the Index, where they are staged and ready for you to finalize into a commit.  Then `git commit` will create the commit which includes all existing files plus the new and changed files in the index.  Finally, you can push you new commit up to the remote with `git push origin`.  Beyond that I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: @Raphael Also, I'd like to mention that the last section of my answer (**How to see changes ready for committing**) explains exactly how to see the file changes that have occurred since the last commit.

Comment: In fact, the stash *is* commits (at least two of them: index, and work-tree), they're just commits that are not on any branch. So you can just say "a temporary commit", without even the "sort of" part. (Because `git stash` (ab)uses the reflog for `refs/stash`, the temporary commits here are much more temporary than are ordinary commits.)

Comment: @torek I understand what you're saying - I could agree with just 'temporary commit'.  I wanted to communicate that they are a bit of a funny thing and be a little bit careful using them if you don't fully understand them.

Comment: I'll put it like this: 
 I do not push changes.. I run only `git pull` command. After each `git pull` some changes will be applied on my working directory. I want to know these changes before 'git pull'.

Comment: Found the solution: It was nothing but diffs in two commits. Used `git diff` command with two commit IDs as argument to get diffs. Thank you @LightCC for all the help. Accepting ur answer.

Comment: @Raphael Okay, I see what you are saying - yes, `git diff` will only show the differences since the last commit, if you actually want to see the difference between this commit and the last one, you can use `git diff HEAD~1..HEAD` or put in the 2 commit hashes as you said.  In Git Extensions, you can just right-click the prior commit and use "Compare > Compare with current branch" to pull up the diff UI with the changes.  Adding that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are *always* on a branch in Git (an exception might the detached head state).  Unless you recall creating a branch, my guess is that you are on the `master` branch.  To see changes you have made relative to where you began, you can use the following from the command line:

```
git diff HEAD
```

If you are using an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, with a Git plugin, then you can visually see many more types of diffs of the files in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps for you to find out. No matter if you create a branch or not, it is easy. Just use

```
git status 
git diff
```

Then all modification you made will be displayed compared to the original master you cloned.

If you already make many changes, then use

```
git diff path/of/file/show/in/git/status
```